# XML Twig delete tags while not generating white space

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I have a huge XML file that contains some  elements. I can use a handler to delete all these elements (one gets replaced and all the others removed). But this creates white space in the document. How can I replace the  elements with 'nothing' so no spaces in the document are created? To be clear the XML data/files I am dealing with are not optimized and contain multiple lines.

Here is a small example of my problem.

XML data:

```
<data>
    <Metadata>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Company>Acme</Company>
    </Metadata>
    <Info>
        <tag r="1"/>
        <tag r="2"/>
        <tag r="3"/>
        <tag r="4"/>
        <tag r="5"/>
        <tag r="6"/>
        <tag r="7"/>
        <tag r="8"/>
        <tag r="9"/>
        <tag r="10"/>
        <tag r="11"/>
        <tag r="12"/>
        <tag r="13"/>
        <tag r="14"/>
        <tag r="15"/>
        <tag r="16"/>
        <tag r="17"/>
        <tag r="18"/>
        <tag r="19"/>
        <tag r="20"/>
    </Info>
</data>
```

After the removal I would like to see

```
<data>
    <Metadata>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Company>Acme</Company>
    </Metadata>
    <Info>
        <Newtag>abc</Newtag>
    </Info>
</data>
```

but instead I get

```
<data>
    <Metadata>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Company>Acme</Company>
    </Metadata>
    <Info>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <Newtag>abc</Newtag>
        
        
        
        
        
    </Info>
</data>
```

So how should my code (below) be modified  so the spaces are not created?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $START_Number=1;
my $END_Number=20;
my $fh1A_file='file containing the XML to modify';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
            pretty_print => 'none',
            twig_roots => {'tag' => sub{modify_datatagX2_TEST1(@_,$START_Number,$END_Number)}},twig_print_outside_roots => 1);
        $twig->parsefile_inplace($fh1A_file);
        $twig->flush;
#
#
#
sub modify_datatagX2_TEST1 {
    my ( $twig, $datatag, $START_Number, $END_Number) = @_;
    my $Match_Found;
    #                      
    if(int($datatag -> att('r'))>$END_Number || int($datatag -> att('r'))<$START_Number){
        $twig->flush;
    } else {
        $Match_Found=0;
        if(int($datatag -> att('r'))>=$START_Number && int($datatag -> att('r'))<=$END_Number){
            $datatag->delete;
            $Match_Found++;
        }
        print '<Newtag>abc</Newtag>' if $Match_Found==1 and int($datatag -> att('r'))==15;
        $twig->flush if $Match_Found==0;
        #END1:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace between tags shouldn't matter to anything else that uses the XML (And it's not so much that it's *created* but that it's just not *removed*), but if it's for cosmetic reasons without wanting to reformat the entire file later... the trick is to only call `flush` after processing all the `tag`'s by adding a new handler for `Info`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $START_Number=1;
my $END_Number=20;
my $fh1A_file='file containing the XML to modify';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print => 'none',
    twig_roots => {
        'Info' => sub { $_[0]->flush },
        'tag' => sub { modify_datatagX2_TEST1(@_, $START_Number, $END_Number) }
    },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1
    );
$twig->parsefile_inplace($fh1A_file);
$twig->flush;

# Note a lot of cleanup here.
sub modify_datatagX2_TEST1 {
    my ($twig, $datatag, $START_Number, $END_Number) = @_;
    # Only fetch the attribute once; no need for int()
    my $r = $datatag->att('r'); 
    if ($r >= $START_Number && $r <= $END_Number){
        # Don't just blindly print text, replace the element in the XML tree on match
        if ($r == 15) {
            my $newtag = XML::Twig::Elt->new(Newtag => 'abc');
            $newtag->replace($datatag);
        } else {
            $datatag->delete;
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce

```xml
<data>
    <Metadata>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Company>Acme</Company>
    </Metadata>
    <Info><Newtag>abc</Newtag></Info>
</data>
```